# Design Web application with spring-mvc, how to choose data, model objects & ui objects?

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I built a web application using spring-boot, spring-mvc and hibernate. I used the DAO in UI directly by just wrapping them in another objects. It makes my DAL and Presentation layer quite tightly coupled.

As per my understanding, mvc architecture reduces coupling by separating out each component and i worked against that. :(

Is it okay to do what i did? As it saves presentation layer object conversion to DAO to persist them in DB.
What is recommended and best way to design? what will the pay-off with current design (quite tightly coupled)?

I'm not able to figure out, could anyone please help me to understand it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I am not clear about your question, you are looking for good architecture to handle your DAL and Rest ?

Comment: @ojuskulkarni : I'm looking best design practices while creating DAO and Objects to capture data from UI. Is it okay to use same object for both?

Answer (score 0):

I used to  do it like that:

I create several layers: the UI layer, the BLL layer and the DAL layer. Then I create the models for each of them. For example: MyUser_UI.java, MyUser_Bll.java and MyUser_Dal.java. This models are so-called POJO, they are used to carry data between layers. As you can see, MyUser_xxx.java(s) have similar property, so I use a automatic object mapper named DozerBeanMapper to help me to transmit data from one to another. That's what I have done.

I promise that is a practical method, however, obviously, it is far from the best. Too many classes I must maintain. Think about that: one day I want to add a new property for MyUser_xxx.java, I must change three places. I often miss something and get errors. So I changed to another way.

I extract the POJO to a separate package. All the three layers can access this package. In doing so, I feel better. But it also brings some other problems. POJOs requirement for each layer is often a bit different. So I have to create the base class MyUser.java, and the MyUserEx.java derived from the base.

It is a bit disappointing that I don't think there is a best design. But we can combine many methods to make our code better. Witch do you prefer? It's up to you.

Comment: I understand, there is no hard and fast rule to be followed but some guidelines to reduce the problems in future. As i mentioned in question itself, i'm also using somewhat similar to your second approach, where i'm wrapping DAO directly to create my UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler has a fairly seminal article on layering from his P of EAA book:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

[image]